# Stripe Invoices - Custom Prices

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a question for anyone familiar with the Stripe Payments API.

#### What I'm Trying to Do

I am trying to create an invoice with a custom, dynamic price. This price might vary between customers by a few cents, so it is not feasible to have hundreds of prices for a single product.

#### The Problem with Invoices/Checkout Session

Usually when a customer activates a subscription or pays for a product, they do so using Invoices. Invoices are created through checkout sessions on our backend like so:

```
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        mode='payment',
        customer=customer_id,
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price': MY_PRICE_ID,
            'quantity': 5,
        }],
    )
```

Checkout sessions allow price IDs but not custom prices! (or do they?)

#### The Problem with Payment Intents

Payment intents let you create checkout sessions with dynamic prices on the client, for example:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount,
        currency: "usd"
});
```

However this will create a charge in the `Customer` that isn't assosciated with any product. I would like to associate this payment with a product.

Answer (score 4):

I found this from Checkout Session Api documentation. It says that, in `line_items` you can either pass `price` or `price_data` or `amount`. If `amount` provided then `currency` and `name` is mandatory.

[image]

So, following code should work for you,

```
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    mode='payment',
    customer=customer_id,
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    line_items=[{
        'amount': MY_AMOUNT,
        'currency': 'USD',
        'name': MY_ITEM,
        'quantity': 5,
        ...
    }],
)
```

If you want to associate the payment with the product then by using `price_data` following code should work for you,

```
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    mode='payment',
    customer=customer_id,
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    line_items=[{
        'price_data':{
            'currency': 'USD',
            'product': MY_PRODUCT_ID,
            'unit_amount': MY_AMOUNT,
            ...
         }
    }],
)
```